# Facebook Share - simulate clicking a link from inside SCRIPT tag

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have following simple page:

```
<body>

<a id='aa' href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=370785493758664&sdk=joey&u=https://citizengo.org/&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=share_button" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Facebook', 'width=640,height=580')">SHARE PAGE</a>

</body>
<script>
document.getElementById('aa').click();
</script>
```

However when loaded, the link is being opened in the same window, but if I comment `document.getElementById('aa').click();` and will invoke it from dev tools' console, it shows beautiful popup! WHY?

I want to trigger the popup on page load. I tried other options, but all of them were leading to 'popup being blocked' by the browser and of course I don't want to ask user to add the exception...

Comment: browsers block those things for a good reason. why would you want to do that?

Comment: That's of course bad UI/UX behavior. However I wanted to give users possibility to tick a checkbox before submitting the form if they want to have this popup automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried other options, but all of them were leading to 'popup being blocked' by the browser

The browser will always block the popup, if you try to trigger it automatically and without proper user interaction.

Try adding `target="_blank"` to the link, and see if it opens a new window/tab then. (Then you won’t be able to specify any dimensions though.)

If that gets caught by the popup blocker as well - then there is no other way.

---

Slamming this dialog into user’s faces without asking, seems a bit aggressive/annoying - sure your visitors will actually like that?

Plus, Facebook might not like it either in the long run, when you *force* this onto people. They might conclude that you are trying to force users to share, or give the impression that sharing was a necessity to use the rest of your site … So don’t be too surprised, should Facebook one day block your domain.

Comment: Yes, I tried it before as well. No effect. Many thanks for your answer. I'm still thinking of smoe other solution like iFrame inside modal however I must go deeper into this topic first...

Comment: You won’t have any luck trying to show this dialog inside an iframe - Facebook sends an `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header, so the user’s browser will simply refuse to display it.